# There is already an object named 'company_names' in the database

Tags: go, go-gorm, golang-migrate

I use Gorm for Golang like this code,

```
func Connect() (*gorm.DB, error) {
var (
    err error
    db  *gorm.DB
)

dsn := "sqlserver://User:12345@127.0.0.1:1433?database=gorm"
db, err = gorm.Open(sqlserver.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

err = db.Debug().AutoMigrate(&models.CompanyName{}, &models.CarModel{}, &models.CreateYear{}, &models.Diversity{})
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

return db, nil
}
```

and in main.go

```
func main() {
db, err := Connect()
if err != nil {
    panic("database connection failed")
}

ech := echo.New()
}
```

Ok in the first time when we run code, gorm create tables in database,but in the second time I got an error thet

> mssql: There is already an object named 'table_names' in the database.

Do I have to delete ***db.Debug().AutoMigrate)(***?